# Automatically bump versions when building a Debian package

Tags: versioning, debian, package, packaging

I have a set of Debian packaging scripts and I would like the version number of the package to be incremented each time it is built. (i.e. *`debian_revision`* as specified in the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version)) That is, the first build should be `PACKAGE-1.0-0`, then `PACKAGE-1.0-0`, and so on (where `1.0` is the *`upstream_version`*). Is there an easy way to specify this "extra" version number without having to create a new entry in the changelog?

I'm looking to have this automatically done by the Makefile for the project whenever a particular target (i.e. `deb` is built)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dh_*` scripts read `debian/changelog` to build a changes file and set the versions, among other things. You should not change the version without editing the changelog, but if your problem is changes made manually you can make a script that invokes

```
dch -i
```

or if your problem is changes made at the `debian/changelog`, you can make a bash script to change the version automatically.

Comment: Don't forget, if you don't want to get to the editor you can use `dch -i "Your message here"` and the changelog will be edited/created without an editor.